# Python and 16-bit PGM

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, 16-bit, pgm

I have 16-bit PGM images that I am trying to read in Python. It seems (?) like PIL does not support this format?

```
import Image
im = Image.open('test.pgm')
im.show()
```

Shows roughly the image, but it isn't right. There are dark bands throughout and img is reported to have `mode=L`. I think this is related to an early question I had about [16-bit TIFF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247371/python-and-16-bit-tiff). Is 16-bit that rare that PIL just does not support it? Any advice how I can read 16-bit PGM files in Python, using PIL or another standard library, or home-grown code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following depends only on [numpy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) to load the image, which can be 8-bit or 16-bit raw PGM/PPM.  I also show a couple different ways to view the image.  The one that uses PIL (`import Image`) requires that the data first be converted to 8-bit.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2 -u

from __future__ import print_function
import sys, numpy

def read_pnm_from_stream( fd ):
   pnm = type('pnm',(object,),{}) ## create an empty container
   pnm.header = fd.readline()
   pnm.magic = pnm.header.split()[0]
   pnm.maxsample = 1 if ( pnm.magic == 'P4' ) else 0
   while ( len(pnm.header.split()) < 3+(1,0)[pnm.maxsample] ): s = fd.readline() ; pnm.header += s if ( len(s) and s[0] != '#' ) else ''
   pnm.width, pnm.height = [int(item) for item in pnm.header.split()[1:3]]
   pnm.samples = 3 if ( pnm.magic == 'P6' ) else 1
   if ( pnm.maxsample == 0 ): pnm.maxsample = int(pnm.header.split()[3])
   pnm.pixels = numpy.fromfile( fd, count=pnm.width*pnm.height*pnm.samples, dtype='u1' if pnm.maxsample < 256 else '>u2' )
   pnm.pixels = pnm.pixels.reshape(pnm.height,pnm.width) if pnm.samples==1 else pnm.pixels.reshape(pnm.height,pnm.width,pnm.samples)
   return pnm

if __name__ == '__main__':

## read image
 # src = read_pnm_from_stream( open(filename) )
   src = read_pnm_from_stream( sys.stdin )
 # print("src.header="+src.header.strip(), file=sys.stderr )
 # print("src.pixels="+repr(src.pixels), file=sys.stderr )

## write image
   dst=src
   dst.pixels = numpy.array([ dst.maxsample-i for i in src.pixels ],dtype=dst.pixels.dtype) ## example image processing
 # print("dst shape: "+str(dst.pixels.shape), file=sys.stderr )
   sys.stdout.write(("P5" if dst.samples==1 else "P6")+"\n"+str(dst.width)+" "+str(dst.height)+"\n"+str(dst.maxsample)+"\n");
   dst.pixels.tofile( sys.stdout ) ## seems to work, I'm not sure how it decides about endianness

## view using Image
   import Image
   viewable = dst.pixels if dst.pixels.dtype == numpy.dtype('u1') else numpy.array([ x>>8 for x in dst.pixels],dtype='u1')
   Image.fromarray(viewable).show()

## view using scipy
   import scipy.misc
   scipy.misc.toimage(dst.pixels).show()
```

---

## Usage notes

- I eventually figured out "how it decides about endianness" -- it is actually storing the image in memory as big-endian (rather than native). This scheme might slow down any non-trivial image processing -- although other performance issues with Python may relegate this concern to a triviality (see below).
- I asked a question related to the endianness concern [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34097845/86967).  I also ran into some interesting confusion related to endianness with this because I was testing by preprocessing the image with `pnmdepth 65535` which is not good (by itself) for testing endianness since the low and high bytes might end up being the same (I didn't notice right away because `print(array)` outputs decimal).  I should have also applied `pnmgamma` to save myself some confusion.
- Because Python is so slow, `numpy` tries to be <s>sneaky</s>clever about how it applies certain operations (see [*broadcasting*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html)).  The first rule of thumb for efficiency with `numpy` is *let numpy handle iteration for you* (or put another way [*don't write your own `for` loops*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18517922)).  The funny thing in the code above is that it only partially follows this rule when doing the "example image processing", and therefore the performance of that line has an extreme dependency on the parameters that were given to `reshape`.
- The next big `numpy` endianness mystery: Why does `newbyteorder()` seem to [return an array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.byteswapping.html), when it's [documented](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.newbyteorder.html) to return a `dtype`.  This is relevant if you want to convert to native endian with `dst.pixels=dst.pixels.byteswap(True).newbyteorder()`.
- Hints on porting to Python 3: [binary input with an ASCII text header, read from stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31488419/86967)

Comment: Why does trying to write seemingly trivial Python programs seem to always result in an odyssey through Stack Overflow?

Comment: One of the things that drives me crazy about Python is shallow copies, such as `dst=src` above.  Sometimes I think that Python is just too difficult for a C++ programmer to understand.

Comment: ...I found some of the lowest voted answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541025/how-to-copy-a-python-class) to be the most useful.  In particular, it looks like I can solve my problem above by doing `dst=src()`.

Answer (score 4):

You need a mode of `"L;16"`; however it looks like PIL has a mode of `"L"` hardcoded into File.c when loading a PGM. You’d have to [write your own decoder](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/decoder.htm) if you want to be able to read a 16-bit PGM.

However, 16-bit image support still seems flaky:

```
>>> im = Image.fromstring('I;16', (16, 16), '\xCA\xFE' * 256, 'raw', 'I;16') 
>>> im.getcolors()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 866, in getcolors
    return self.im.getcolors(maxcolors)
ValueError: image has wrong mode
```

I think PIL is capable of *reading* images with 16 bits, but actually storing and manipulating them is still experimental.

```
>>> im = Image.fromstring('L', (16, 16), '\xCA\xFE' * 256, 'raw', 'L;16') 
>>> im
<Image.Image image mode=L size=16x16 at 0x27B4440>
>>> im.getcolors()
[(256, 254)]
```

See, it just interpreted the `0xCAFE` value as `0xFE`, which isn’t exactly correct.

Comment: I'm happy to just read them. If I need to write I will use PNG. I am also OK with manipulating them as data in numpy rather than as an image in PIL. Your post has been helpful, but can you expand on how I can correctly read in the data?

Comment: Do you mean writing a decoder for PIL, or how to interpret the PGM?

Comment: Your italicized '''reading''' made me think there is some trick to perhaps make it work as-is? I'm trying to adapt the work-around here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247371/python-and-16-bit-tiff) but without losing bits. If a custom decoder is needed I will write it based on the PIL tutorial. The PGM format seems pretty basic, so perhaps I should just read it directly into numpy...

Comment: I’m not sure. In my test, it correctly parsed the file but was unable to represent its contents exactly. I don’t think using a custom decoder would have a different result than using fromstring. Numpy is probably a better bet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic [PNM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pnm.html)/[PAM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pam.html) reader based on [NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/numpy/info) and an undocumented function in [PyPNG](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pypng/info).

```
def read_pnm( filename, endian='>' ):
   fd = open(filename,'rb')
   format, width, height, samples, maxval = png.read_pnm_header( fd )
   pixels = numpy.fromfile( fd, dtype='u1' if maxval < 256 else endian+'u2' )
   return pixels.reshape(height,width,samples)
```

Of course *writing* this image format generally doesn't require the assistance of a library...

Comment: I borrowed some ideas from [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368739/numpy-and-16-bit-pgm).

Comment: With regards to 'PAM' support, the `read_pnm_header()` function used here doesn't return `TUPLTYPE`, but it does return the correct value for `DEPTH` (which I called `samples`).

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850893/reading-binary-data-from-stdin) for important notes on using stdio instead of a file.

Comment: It's been a while, and I'm not sure where `endian` was supposed to have come from.  I think it should just be replaced with `'>'` to indicate that the file is stored as big-endian (per the [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Netpbm_format&oldid=672069881#16-bit_extensions)).