# Get Image size WITHOUT loading image into memory

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I understand that you can get the image size using PIL in the following fashion

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(image_filename)
width, height = im.size
```

However, I would like to get the image width and height *without* having to load the image in memory. Is that possible? I am only doing statistics on image sizes and dont care for the image contents. I just want to make my processing faster.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I don't believe that `.open()` reads the entire file into memory... (that's what `.load()`) does - so as far as I know - this is as good as it gets using `PIL`

Comment: Even if you think you have a function that only reads the image header information, filesystem readahead code may still load the whole image.  Worrying about performance is unproductive unless your application requires it.

Comment: A quick memory test using `pmap` to monitor the memory used by a process shows me that indeed `PIL` does not load the entire image in memory.

Comment: See also: [Get image dimensions with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34704661/562769)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

As the comments allude, PIL does not load the image into memory when calling `.open`. Looking at the docs of `PIL 1.1.7`, the docstring for `.open` says:

```
def open(fp, mode="r"):
    "Open an image file, without loading the raster data"
```

There are a few file operations in the source like:

```
 ...
 prefix = fp.read(16)
 ...
 fp.seek(0)
 ...
```

but these hardly constitute reading the whole file. In fact `.open` simply returns a file object and the filename on success. In addition the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/1.7.8/pythondoc-PIL.Image.html) say:

> open(file, mode=”r”)
>
> Opens and identifies the given image file.
>
> This is a lazy operation; this function identifies the file, but the actual image data is not read from the file until you try to process the data (or call the **load** method).

Digging deeper, we see that `.open` calls `_open` which is a image-format specific overload. Each of the implementations to `_open` can be found in a new file, eg. .jpeg files are in `JpegImagePlugin.py`. Let's look at that one in depth.

Here things seem to get a bit tricky, in it there is an infinite loop that gets broken out of when the jpeg marker is found:

```
    while True:

        s = s + self.fp.read(1)
        i = i16(s)

        if i in MARKER:
            name, description, handler = MARKER[i]
            # print hex(i), name, description
            if handler is not None:
                handler(self, i)
            if i == 0xFFDA: # start of scan
                rawmode = self.mode
                if self.mode == "CMYK":
                    rawmode = "CMYK;I" # assume adobe conventions
                self.tile = [("jpeg", (0,0) + self.size, 0, (rawmode, ""))]
                # self.__offset = self.fp.tell()
                break
            s = self.fp.read(1)
        elif i == 0 or i == 65535:
            # padded marker or junk; move on
            s = "\xff"
        else:
            raise SyntaxError("no marker found")
```

Which looks like it *could* read the whole file if it was malformed. If it reads the info marker OK however, it should break out early. The function `handler` ultimately sets `self.size` which are the dimensions of the image.

Comment: True enough, but does `open` get the *size* of the image or is that a lazy operation too? And if it's lazy, does it read the image data at the same time?

Comment: The doc link points to Pillow a fork from PIL. I cannot however find an official doc link on the web. If someone posts it as a comment I'll update the answer. The quote can be found in the file `Docs/PIL.Image.html`.

Comment: @MarkRansom I've attempted to answer your question, however to be 100% sure it looks like we have to dive into each image-specific implementation. The `.jpeg` format looks OK as long as the header is found.

Comment: @Hooked: Thanks very much for looking into this. I accept that you are correct although I quite like Paulo's rather minimal solution below (even though to be fair the OP did not mention wanting to avoid the PIL dependency)

Comment: @AlexFlint No problem, it's always fun to poke around the code. I'd say that Paulo earned his bounty though, that's a nice snippet he wrote for you there.

Comment: for the one who came here 10 years later:
this answer is correct for both jpg and png, it's WAY faster than cv2.imread

Answer (score 125):

If you don't care about the image contents, PIL is probably an overkill.

I suggest parsing the output of the python magic module:

```
>>> t = magic.from_file('teste.png')
>>> t
'PNG image data, 782 x 602, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced'
>>> re.search('(\d+) x (\d+)', t).groups()
('782', '602')
```

This is a wrapper around libmagic which read as few bytes as possible in order to identify a file type signature.

Relevant version of script:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scardine/image_size/master/get_image_size.py

[update]

> Hmmm, unfortunately, when applied to jpegs, the above gives "'JPEG image data, EXIF standard 2.21'". No image size! – Alex Flint

Seems like jpegs are magic-resistant. :-)

I can see why: in order to get the image dimensions for JPEG files, you may have to read more bytes than libmagic likes to read.

Rolled up my sleeves and came with [this very untested snippet (get it from GitHub)](https://github.com/scardine/image_size) that requires no third-party modules.

[image: Look, Ma! No deps!]

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        get_image_size
# Purpose:     extract image dimensions given a file path using just
#              core modules
#
# Author:      Paulo Scardine (based on code from Emmanuel VAÏSSE)
#
# Created:     26/09/2013
# Copyright:   (c) Paulo Scardine 2013
# Licence:     MIT
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import struct

class UnknownImageFormat(Exception):
    pass

def get_image_size(file_path):
    """
    Return (width, height) for a given img file content - no external
    dependencies except the os and struct modules from core
    """
    size = os.path.getsize(file_path)

    with open(file_path) as input:
        height = -1
        width = -1
        data = input.read(25)

        if (size >= 10) and data[:6] in ('GIF87a', 'GIF89a'):
            # GIFs
            w, h = struct.unpack("<HH", data[6:10])
            width = int(w)
            height = int(h)
        elif ((size >= 24) and data.startswith('\211PNG\r\n\032\n')
              and (data[12:16] == 'IHDR')):
            # PNGs
            w, h = struct.unpack(">LL", data[16:24])
            width = int(w)
            height = int(h)
        elif (size >= 16) and data.startswith('\211PNG\r\n\032\n'):
            # older PNGs?
            w, h = struct.unpack(">LL", data[8:16])
            width = int(w)
            height = int(h)
        elif (size >= 2) and data.startswith('\377\330'):
            # JPEG
            msg = " raised while trying to decode as JPEG."
            input.seek(0)
            input.read(2)
            b = input.read(1)
            try:
                while (b and ord(b) != 0xDA):
                    while (ord(b) != 0xFF): b = input.read(1)
                    while (ord(b) == 0xFF): b = input.read(1)
                    if (ord(b) >= 0xC0 and ord(b) <= 0xC3):
                        input.read(3)
                        h, w = struct.unpack(">HH", input.read(4))
                        break
                    else:
                        input.read(int(struct.unpack(">H", input.read(2))[0])-2)
                    b = input.read(1)
                width = int(w)
                height = int(h)
            except struct.error:
                raise UnknownImageFormat("StructError" + msg)
            except ValueError:
                raise UnknownImageFormat("ValueError" + msg)
            except Exception as e:
                raise UnknownImageFormat(e.__class__.__name__ + msg)
        else:
            raise UnknownImageFormat(
                "Sorry, don't know how to get information from this file."
            )

    return width, height
```

[update 2019]

Check out a Rust implementation: https://github.com/scardine/imsz

Comment: Aren't `python-magic` and `PIL` separate libraries? You should make it clear that this answer doesn't involve `PIL`.

Comment: The OP doesn't ask for a PIL specific solution despite the question being tagged image-processing. In fact PIL seems to be an overkill for his use case since he doesn't care about the file contents and will not do any image processing.

Comment: I didn't mean any offense, I just wanted to point out that this is not a specific `PIL` answer (since it was tagged and mentioned in the post). FWIW: a counter-point to your overkill comment is that `PIL` is, at least for this process, self-contained without needing access to `libmagic`.

Comment: PIL is way larger. I would not trade the dependency on libmagic (present by default in most environments) for PIL's multitude of dependencies (like libjpeg, libpng and so on). In this regard, libmagic is more self-contained.

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem. I will wait a couple of days to see if anyone posts a solution that doesn't involve string parsing but otherwise you'll get the bounty.

Comment: Hmmm unfortunately when applied to jpegs, the above gives "'JPEG image data, EXIF standard 2.21'". No image size!

Comment: @AlexFlint: would you like to compare results from this snippet against the solution using PIL?

Comment: @PauloScardine Your edit is perhaps why the PIL code for the metadata has an infinite loop - interesting find!

Comment: @PauloScardine hey thanks Paulo, this is great! It's always so nice to have code that can be easily deployed without brining in dependencies, and this fits the bill! As you say, avoiding PIL is worth it for its own sake. (stackoverflow tells me that I must wait another 12 hours before awarding the bounty.)

Comment: This doesn't read ICO files, but [this one does](https://gist.github.com/EJEHardenberg/8240859) I've added in handling  .ico files here. I didn't want to edit the answer because I imagine there's a better way to check for the ico file itself besides the extension

Comment: I also added the capability to retrieve number of channels (not to be confused w/ bit depth) in the comment after [the version @EJEHardenberg provides above](https://gist.github.com/EJEHardenberg/8240859).

Comment: Great thing. I added support for bitmaps in the GitHub project. Thanks!

Comment: NOTE: the current version does not work for me. @PauloScardine has an updated working version on https://github.com/scardine/image_size

Comment: Get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte` on MacOS, python3 on `data = input.read(25)` , `file` on image gives `PNG image data, 720 x 857, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced`

Comment: Seems code from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scardine/image_size/master/get_image_size.py works.

Comment: Very cool, thanks! I used this in a local script and also extended it with a few more file formats, see: https://github.com/panzi/get_image_size.py Most important additions that I needed: WEBP and AVIF

Answer (score 79):

There is a package on pypi called `imagesize` that currently works for me, although it doesn't look like it is very active.

Install:

```
pip install imagesize
```

Usage:

```
import imagesize

width, height = imagesize.get("test.png")
print(width, height)
```

Homepage: https://github.com/shibukawa/imagesize_py

PyPi: https://pypi.org/project/imagesize/

Comment: I compared the speed imagesize.get, magic.from_file, and PIL image to get the actual image size by timeit. The results showed that speed imagesize.get (0.019s) > PIL(0.104s) > magic with regex (0.1699s).

Comment: I can confirm, imagesize works very well, Very efficient for simply getting the dimensions of an image

Comment: @RyanLiu I find the inverted direction of the `>` sign very confusing. Isn't the time *smaller*?

Comment: @Gulzar FYI - I think the `>` sign applies to the speed (ie. faster > slower), but then he put the time in parentheses, which does not agree with the sign.

Comment: Note, however, that imagesize does not look at the EXIF rotation of the image, so if the image is rotated using an EXIF header the width and height will be swapped. [A feature request was opened in 2021](https://github.com/shibukawa/imagesize_py/issues/49) but no answer from the author yet.

Comment: In our image inference databricks job, there were some gigantic images that made opencv fail like this: `Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:79: error: (-215:Assertion failed) pixels <= CV_IO_MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS in function 'validateInputImageSize''` even after setting the environment variable CV_IO_MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS to a very large value. Using this library now to avoid processing gigantic images. Thx.

Answer (score 15):

The OP was interested in a "faster" solution, I was curious about the fastest solution and I am trying to answer that with a real-world benchmark.

I am comparing:

- `cv2.imread`: https://www.kite.com/python/docs/cv2.imread
- `PIL.open`: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html
- `opsdroid/image_size`: https://github.com/opsdroid/image_size (packaged version of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scardine/image_size/master/get_image_size.py)
- `shibukawa/imagesize_py`: https://github.com/shibukawa/imagesize_py
- `kobaltcore/pymage_size`: https://github.com/kobaltcore/pymage_size

I am running the following code on 202897 mostly JPG files.

```
"""
pip install opsdroid-get-image-size --user
pip install pymage_size
pip install imagesize
"""

import concurrent.futures
from pathlib import Path

import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
from PIL import Image
import get_image_size
import imagesize
import pymage_size

files = [str(p.resolve())
         for p in Path("/data/").glob("**/*")
         if p.suffix in {".jpg", ".jpeg", ".JPEG", ".JPG", ".png", ".PNG"}]

def get_shape_cv2(fname):
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    return (img.shape[0], img.shape[1])

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(8) as executor:
    results = list(tqdm(executor.map(get_shape_cv2, files), total=len(files)))

def get_shape_pil(fname):
    img=Image.open(fname)
    return (img.size[0], img.size[1])

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(8) as executor:
    results = list(tqdm(executor.map(get_shape_pil, files), total=len(files)))

def get_shape_scardine_size(fname):
    try:
        width, height = get_image_size.get_image_size(fname)
    except get_image_size.UnknownImageFormat:
        width, height = -1, -1
    return (width, height)

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(8) as executor:
    results = list(tqdm(executor.map(get_shape_scardine_size, files), total=len(files)))

def get_shape_shibukawa(fname):
    width, height = imagesize.get(fname)
    return (width, height)

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(8) as executor:
    results = list(tqdm(executor.map(get_shape_shibukawa, files), total=len(files)))

def get_shape_pymage_size(fname):
    img_format = pymage_size.get_image_size(fname)
    width, height = img_format.get_dimensions()
    return (width, height)

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(8) as executor:
    results = list(tqdm(executor.map(get_shape_pymage_size, files), total=len(files)))
```

Results:

- `cv2.imread`: 8m23s
- `PIL.open`: 2m00s
- `opsdroid/image_size`: 29s
- `shibukawa/imagesize_py`: 29s
- `kobaltcore/pymage_size`: 29s

So the opsdroid, shibukawa and kobaltcore perform at the same speed. Another interesting point for me would now be to better understand which of the libraries has the best format support.

[EDIT]
So I went ahead and tested if the fast libraries provide different results:

```
# test if the libs provide the same results
def show_size_differences(fname):
    w1, h1 = get_shape_scardine_size(fname)
    w2, h2 = get_shape_pymage_size(fname)
    w3, h3 = get_shape_shibukawa(fname)
    if w1 != w2 or w2 != w3 or h1 != h2 or h2 != h3:
        print(f"scardine: {w1}x{h1}, pymage: {w2}x{h2}, shibukawa: {w3}x{h3}")

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(8) as executor:
    results = list(tqdm(executor.map(show_size_differences, files), total=len(files)))
```

And they don't.

Comment: But why they are slow? What if they are just easy bugs in popular libraries?

Comment: Please add from scardine too!

Comment: scardine and opsdroid are the same, see readme of scardine

Answer (score 11):

I often fetch image sizes on the Internet. Of course, you can't download the image and then load it to parse the information. It's too time consuming. My method is to feed chunks to an image container and test whether it can parse the image every time. Stop the loop when I get the information I want.

I extracted the core of my code and modified it to parse local files.

```
from PIL import ImageFile

ImPar=ImageFile.Parser()
with open(r"D:\testpic\test.jpg", "rb") as f:
    ImPar=ImageFile.Parser()
    chunk = f.read(2048)
    count=2048
    while chunk != "":
        ImPar.feed(chunk)
        if ImPar.image:
            break
        chunk = f.read(2048)
        count+=2048
    print(ImPar.image.size)
    print(count)
```

Output:

```
(2240, 1488)
38912
```

The actual file size is 1,543,580 bytes and you only read 38,912 bytes to get the image size. Hope this will help.

Comment: Not very smart with count+=2048 every time. Linear...

Answer (score 2):

Another short way of doing it on Unix systems. It depends on the output of `file` which I am not sure is standardized on all systems. This should probably not be used in production code. Moreover most JPEGs don't report the image size.

```
import subprocess, re
image_size = list(map(int, re.findall('(\d+)x(\d+)', subprocess.getoutput("file " + filename))[-1]))
```

Comment: Gives `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: this worked for me when i ran the python file directly. But when i tried to docker containerize my codes the following Error is thrown
`IndexError: list index out of range`
It seems the following command was not able to find my file inside docker container
`subprocess.getoutput("file " + filename) `

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20380514/153487) has an another good resolution, but missing the *pgm* format. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7369986/153487) has resolved the *pgm*. And I add the *bmp*.

Codes is below

```
import struct, imghdr, re, magic

def get_image_size(fname):
    '''Determine the image type of fhandle and return its size.
    from draco'''
    with open(fname, 'rb') as fhandle:
        head = fhandle.read(32)
        if len(head) != 32:
            return
        if imghdr.what(fname) == 'png':
            check = struct.unpack('>i', head[4:8])[0]
            if check != 0x0d0a1a0a:
                return
            width, height = struct.unpack('>ii', head[16:24])
        elif imghdr.what(fname) == 'gif':
            width, height = struct.unpack('<HH', head[6:10])
        elif imghdr.what(fname) == 'jpeg':
            try:
                fhandle.seek(0) # Read 0xff next
                size = 2
                ftype = 0
                while not 0xc0 <= ftype <= 0xcf:
                    fhandle.seek(size, 1)
                    byte = fhandle.read(1)
                    while ord(byte) == 0xff:
                        byte = fhandle.read(1)
                    ftype = ord(byte)
                    size = struct.unpack('>H', fhandle.read(2))[0] - 2
                # We are at a SOFn block
                fhandle.seek(1, 1)  # Skip `precision' byte.
                height, width = struct.unpack('>HH', fhandle.read(4))
            except Exception: #IGNORE:W0703
                return
        elif imghdr.what(fname) == 'pgm':
            header, width, height, maxval = re.search(
                b"(^P5\s(?:\s*#.*[\r\n])*"
                b"(\d+)\s(?:\s*#.*[\r\n])*"
                b"(\d+)\s(?:\s*#.*[\r\n])*"
                b"(\d+)\s(?:\s*#.*[\r\n]\s)*)", head).groups()
            width = int(width)
            height = int(height)
        elif imghdr.what(fname) == 'bmp':
            _, width, height, depth = re.search(
                b"((\d+)\sx\s"
                b"(\d+)\sx\s"
                b"(\d+))", str).groups()
            width = int(width)
            height = int(height)
        else:
            return
        return width, height
```

Comment: `imghdr` however handles certain jpegs quite poorly.

Answer (score 1):

Beside this is a very old question, I tried several of these approaches but nothing works for my large 3D Tif-File. So here is a very easy and fast solution, using the "tifffile" package "memmap" function:

```
    import tifffile
    memmap_image = tifffile.memmap(fp)
    memmap_image.shape
```

Runtime for my 450 GB 32bit Tif-Image: 10 milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

I tried:

1. magic library
2. PIL (Python Image Library)
3. imagesize library

What I discovered:

1. Using regex to parse the string output from **magic** is unreliable because the string output is different for all file types. If your system accepts several or many different image types, you'd have to make sure you're parsing the string output correctly. See my test's output below to for what the string output looks like for each file type.
2. **imagesize** library is not very robust. Out of the box currently, it analyzes JPEG/JPEG 2000/PNG/GIF/TIFF/SVG/Netpbm/WebP. When it tries to find the image size of a file it's not equipped to handle, it gives you a size of `(-1, -1)`. You can see this in my .BMP example below.

**My Conclusion** - I would choose `PIL`. It's not as fast as `imagesize` library, but it is more robust to handle more file types. I also think it's "fast enough" for most use-cases. Using `re` to parse the `magic` output is not reliable, and it's much slower compared to `PIL`.

**My Test**

I took a saved image on my hard drive (636 x 636) and saved it into 6 different file formats (.png, .jpg, .jpeg, .tif, .tiff, .bmp). The images and the script were all saved in the same directory. The file *sizes* of each file type in my test are commented out below next to the file names.

The script:

```
import os
import re
import timeit
import magic
import imagesize

import time
from PIL import Image



"""
Notes:
 - all images are the same image saved as different formats
 - file extensions tested are: .png, .jpg, .jpeg, .tif, .tiff, .bmp
 - all images in this test are size 636 x 636
 - all images are in the same directory as this script

If you want to setup this similar experiment, take a single image,
save it as: png_image.png, jpg_image.jpg, jpeg_image.jpeg, tif_image.tif,
tiff_image.tiff, and bmp_image.bmp (others if you'd like),
in the same directory as this script, and run this script.
Or name the images whatever and modify the script below. You do you.
"""

NUMBER = 10000
REPEAT = 5

def regex(filename):
    name,ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if ext.lower() in ['.tif', '.tiff']:
        return '^(?=.*width=(\d+))(?=.*height=(\d+))'
    elif ext.lower() in ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png']:
        return '(\d+)\s?x\s?(\d+)'
    elif ext.lower() in ['.bmp']:
        return '(\d+)\s?x\s?(\d+)\s?x\s?\d+'
    else:
        raise Exception('Extension %s is not accounted for.' % ext.lower())

PNG_FILE = 'png_image.png' # 559 KB
JPG_FILE = 'jpg_image.jpg' # 94 KB
JPEG_FILE = 'jpeg_image.jpeg' # 94 KB
TIF_FILE = 'tif_image.tif' # 768 KB
TIFF_FILE = 'tiff_image.tiff' # 768 KB
BMP_FILE = 'bmp_image.bmp' # 1,581 KB

FILENAMES = [PNG_FILE, JPG_FILE, JPEG_FILE, TIF_FILE, TIFF_FILE, BMP_FILE]

now = time.time()
for filename in FILENAMES:
    print('#' * 36)
    print((" Testing %s" % filename).center(36, "#"))
    print('#' * 36)

    print('# ' + 'magic library'.center(32) + ' #')
    print('  ', 'output:', magic.from_file(filename))
    print('  ', "Size:", re.findall(regex(filename), magic.from_file(filename))[-1])
    print('  ', "Regex used:", regex(filename))
    
    print('# ' + 'PIL library'.center(32) + ' #')
    image = Image.open(filename)
    print('  ', image)
    print('  ', "Size:", image.size)
    print('  ', "Regex used:", 'None')

    print('# ' + 'imagesize library'.center(32) + ' #')
    image = imagesize.get(filename)
    print('  ', "Size:", image)
    print('  ', "Regex used:", 'None')

    print('-' * 30 + '\n')

print("#################################end#######################################\n")

start = time.time()
for filename in FILENAMES:
    print((" Testing %s " % filename).center(36, "#"))
    
    # magic library
    magic_timer = timeit.Timer(
        stmt="width, height = re.findall(pattern, magic.from_file(filename))[-1]",
        setup="import magic; import re; filename='" + filename + "'; pattern=r'" + regex(filename) + "';",
    )

    magic_timeit = magic_timer.timeit(number=NUMBER)
    magic_repeat = magic_timer.repeat(repeat=REPEAT, number=NUMBER)
    print('magic'.ljust(12) + ":", "%.15f," % magic_timeit, "%s repeat avg. : %.15f" % (REPEAT, sum(magic_repeat) / REPEAT))

    # PIL library
    pillow_timer = timeit.Timer(
        stmt="width, height = Image.open(filename).size;",
        setup="from PIL import Image; filename='" + filename + "';",
    )

    pillow_timeit = pillow_timer.timeit(number=NUMBER)
    pillow_repeat = pillow_timer.repeat(repeat=REPEAT, number=NUMBER)
    print('PIL'.ljust(12) + ":", "%.15f," % pillow_timeit, "%s repeat avg. : %.15f" % (REPEAT, sum(pillow_repeat) / REPEAT))


    # imagesize library
    imagesize_timer = timeit.Timer(
        stmt="width, height = imagesize.get(filename);",
        setup="import imagesize; filename='" + filename + "';",
    )

    imagesize_timeit = imagesize_timer.timeit(number=NUMBER)
    imagesize_repeat = imagesize_timer.repeat(repeat=REPEAT, number=NUMBER)
    print('imagesize'.ljust(12) + ":", "%.15f," % imagesize_timeit, "%s repeat avg. : %.15f" % (REPEAT, sum(imagesize_repeat) / REPEAT))

stop = time.time()
mins, secs = divmod(stop - start, 60)
print('\nTest time: %d minutes %d seconds' % (mins, secs)) 

print("\n#################################end#######################################\n")
```

The output:

```
####################################
####### Testing png_image.png#######
####################################
#          magic library           #
   output: PNG image data, 636 x 636, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
   Size: ('636', '636')
   Regex used: (\d+)\s?x\s?(\d+)
#           PIL library            #
   <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=636x636 at 0x1EBDE962710>
   Size: (636, 636)
   Regex used: None
#        imagesize library         #
   Size: (636, 636)
   Regex used: None
------------------------------

####################################
####### Testing jpg_image.jpg#######
####################################
#          magic library           #
   output: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 96x96, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 636x636, frames 3
   Size: ('636', '636')
   Regex used: (\d+)\s?x\s?(\d+)
#           PIL library            #
   <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=636x636 at 0x1EBDF3E1810>
   Size: (636, 636)
   Regex used: None
#        imagesize library         #
   Size: (636, 636)
   Regex used: None
------------------------------

####################################
###### Testing jpeg_image.jpeg######
####################################
#          magic library           #
   output: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, resolution (DPI), density 96x96, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 636x636, frames 3
   Size: ('636', '636')
   Regex used: (\d+)\s?x\s?(\d+)
#           PIL library            #
   <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=636x636 at 0x1EBDF3E3010>
   Size: (636, 636)
   Regex used: None
#        imagesize library         #
   Size: (636, 636)
   Regex used: None
------------------------------

####################################
####### Testing tif_image.tif#######
####################################
#          magic library           #
   output: TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=16, height=636, bps=63732, compression=LZW, PhotometricIntepretation=RGB, width=636
   Size: ('636', '636')
   Regex used: ^(?=.*width=(\d+))(?=.*height=(\d+))
#           PIL library            #
   <PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=RGBA size=636x636 at 0x1EBDF3E1810>
   Size: (636, 636)
   Regex used: None
#        imagesize library         #
   Size: (636, 636)
   Regex used: None
------------------------------

####################################
###### Testing tiff_image.tiff######
####################################
#          magic library           #
   output: TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=16, height=636, bps=63732, compression=LZW, PhotometricIntepretation=RGB, width=636
   Size: ('636', '636')
   Regex used: ^(?=.*width=(\d+))(?=.*height=(\d+))
#           PIL library            #
   <PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=RGBA size=636x636 at 0x1EBDF3E3160>
   Size: (636, 636)
   Regex used: None
#        imagesize library         #
   Size: (636, 636)
   Regex used: None
------------------------------

####################################
####### Testing bmp_image.bmp#######
####################################
#          magic library           #
   output: PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format, 636 x 636 x 32
   Size: ('636', '636')
   Regex used: (\d+)\s?x\s?(\d+)\s?x\s?\d+
#           PIL library            #
   <PIL.BmpImagePlugin.BmpImageFile image mode=RGB size=636x636 at 0x1EBDF3E31F0>
   Size: (636, 636)
   Regex used: None
#        imagesize library         #
   Size: (-1, -1)
   Regex used: None
------------------------------

#################################end#######################################
```

The timing comparisons of each library / method.
I set `timeit` to 10,000 times, and repeat of 5. For reference, it took 7 minutes 46 seconds to run.

```
###### Testing png_image.png #######
magic       : 9.280310999951325 , 5 repeat avg. : 8.674063340038993
PIL         : 1.069168900023215 , 5 repeat avg. : 1.100983139988966
imagesize   : 0.676764299976639 , 5 repeat avg. : 0.658798480057158
###### Testing jpg_image.jpg #######
magic       : 7.006248699966818 , 5 repeat avg. : 6.803474060003646
PIL         : 1.295019199955277 , 5 repeat avg. : 1.230920840008184
imagesize   : 0.709322200040333 , 5 repeat avg. : 0.706342480005696
##### Testing jpeg_image.jpeg ######
magic       : 6.531979499966837 , 5 repeat avg. : 6.501230620010756
PIL         : 1.263985900091939 , 5 repeat avg. : 1.263613799982704
imagesize   : 0.666680400026962 , 5 repeat avg. : 0.701455319998786
###### Testing tif_image.tif #######
magic       : 11.265482199960388, 5 repeat avg. : 11.423775779991411
PIL         : 3.702962300041690 , 5 repeat avg. : 3.857250300026499
imagesize   : 0.764358000014909 , 5 repeat avg. : 0.750753180007450
##### Testing tiff_image.tiff ######
magic       : 11.288321400061250, 5 repeat avg. : 11.339019200019539
PIL         : 4.116472600027919 , 5 repeat avg. : 3.834464759984985
imagesize   : 0.753993199905381 , 5 repeat avg. : 0.758465819992125
###### Testing bmp_image.bmp #######
magic       : 16.124460300081410, 5 repeat avg. : 16.291060140007176
PIL         : 0.919579099980183 , 5 repeat avg. : 0.928753740014508
imagesize   : 0.649574000039138 , 5 repeat avg. : 0.654250180022791

Test time: 7 minutes 46 seconds

#################################end#######################################
```

**Note**: I'm no timing expert, so if my timing approach seems invalid, please point it out.

Answer (score 0):

Skip straight to the EXIF data and store an integer.

```
from PIL import Image
img_x = Image.open(image_filename)._getexif()[40962]
img_y = Image.open(image_filename)._getexif()[40963]
```

See [this page](https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/privateifd/exif.html) for EXIF tags.