# Efficient way to delete image of the same size

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have many images in a folder and I am want to delete images of the same size. My code below, using PIL, works but I want to know if there is a more efficient way to achieve this.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

def checkImages(dirs):
  image_list = os.listdir(dirs)
  for i in range(len(image_list)):
      for j in range(i + 1, len(image_list)):
        im_a = Image.open(dirs + '/' + image_list[i])
        im_b = Image.open(dirs + '/' + image_list[j])
        if im_a.size == im_b.size:
          os.remove(dirs + '/' + image_list[j])
          del image_list[j]

checkImages('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/testdata')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a dictionary of sizes and delete any images that have a size that have already been seen. That way you don't need a nested loop, and don't have to create Image objects for the same file multiple times.

```
def checkImages(dirs):
  sizes = {}
  for file in os.listdir(dirs):
      size = Image.open(dirs + '/' + file).size
      if size in sizes:
         os.remove(dirs + '/' + file)
      else:
         sizes[size] = file
```

Comment: This can also be combined with the _imagesize_ library suggested by the other answer, which might help speed up the operation further.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this one [Get Image size WITHOUT loading image into memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800704/get-image-size-without-loading-image-into-memory)

you can use the library imagesize

```
import os
import imagesize

def checkImages(dirs):
  image_list = os.listdir(dirs)
  for i in range(len(image_list)):
      for j in range(i + 1, len(image_list)):
        im_a=imagesize.get(dirs+'/'+image_list[i])
        im_b=imagesize.get(dirs+'/'+image_list[j])
        if im_a == im_b:
          os.remove(dirs + '/' + image_list[j])
          del image_list[j]

checkImages('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/testdata')
```

Comment: I believe your approach is using a different library instead of `PIL`. Not sure if it makes so much difference from my approach.

Comment: According to the benchmark on github, there could be a noticeable speed improvent over PIL (Pillow). https://github.com/shibukawa/imagesize_py#benchmark

Comment: Its just a different library which is faster than PIL and it does not load image in memory. 
Combine the imagesize library approach with the other answer and it will be most efficient.