# reading pgm images with cv2 in python

Tags: python, opencv, pgm

I want to read pgm image in python. I use cv2.imread('a.pgm') but it returns wrong results. In Matlab, I use imread and get the right result which is a single channel 16-bit image. But cv2.imread in python returns a 3-channel image and the pixel values are also wrong.
Why it happens?
How should I read the 16-bit pgm images in python?
And what libraries?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [OpenCV supports PGM images](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gsc.tab=0). Please share your code/output/results/errors.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7369986/4014959), which just uses Numpy, may be helpful. Note that some programs use native endian instead of big endian, but it looks like that answer's code handles that.

Comment: Try using  the python equivalent of this: `imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_UNCHANGED)`. Your image should be the same as matlab, eventually different by a scale factor.

Answer (score 10):

I got it.

```py
cv2.imread('a.pgm',-1)
```

works.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use skimage.io library

```
from skimage.io import imread
image = imread("a.pgm")
```