# How to read PGM image in Python

Tags: python, image, data-science, pgm

How to read this PGM image in python? please help

[PGM image link](https://files.fm/u/aag76cpe)

I tried this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def readpgm(name):
    with open(name) as f:
         lines = f.readlines()

    # Ignores commented lines
    for l in list(lines):
            if l[0] == '#':
            lines.remove(l)

    # Makes sure it is ASCII format (P2)
    assert lines[0].strip() == 'P2' 

    # Converts data to a list of integers
    data = []
    for line in lines[1:]:
        data.extend([int(c) for c in line.split()])

    return (np.array(data[3:]),(data[1],data[0]),data[2])

data = readpgm('514516.pgm')

plt.imshow(np.reshape(data[0],data[1])) # Usage example
```

it gives me this error:

```
"return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]

 UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 
 2075: character maps to <undefined>"
```

what should i do? please help

Solution:

[Numpy and 16-bit PGM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368739/numpy-and-16-bit-pgm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image isn't `P2` (ASCII greyscale), it is `P5` (Binary Greyscale).

If you want to convert it to `P2`, you can use **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distort and is available for macOS and Windows.

```
convert YourP5Image.pgm -compress none ActualP2Image.pgm
```

Or, find the Python way of reading binary NetPBM images. It is 16-bit, by the way.