# Python: deepcopy does not work on user-defined classes?

Tags: python, deep-copy

In the following example I would expect deepcopy to create a copy of field and not just copy the reference. What happens here and is there an easy way around it?

```
from copy import deepcopy

class Test:
    field = [(1,2)]

t1 = Test()
t2 = deepcopy(t1)

t2.field[0]=(5,10)

print t1.field # [(1,2)] expected but [(5,10)] obtained
print t2.field # [(5,10)] expected
```

Output:

```
[(5, 10)]
[(5, 10)]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy a python class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541025/how-to-copy-a-python-class)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Deep copying (by default) only applies to instance level attributes - not class level - It doesn't make much sense that there's more than one unique `class.attribute`...

Change your code to:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.field = [(1,2)]
```

Comment: Unless he overrides `__copy__`/`__deepcopy__`.  Still though, that would be pretty odd.

Comment: This is actually not an answer to the question, but a workaround to the problem. If you dont want to/cant instantiate the class in every case, e.g.: you have a `@classmethod`, you cannot apply this workaround...

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with python 3.8 (I am not sure about previous versions) could be creating a `__init__` method that deep-copies every class level attribute, like:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class Test:
    field = [(1,2)]
    def __init__(self):
        for attr in dir(self):
            if not attr.startswith('_'):
                setattr(self, attr, deepcopy(getattr(self, attr)))

t1 = Test()
t2 = deepcopy(t1)

t2.field[0]=(5,10)

print(t1.field) # [(1,2)]
print(t2.field) # [(5,10)]
```

of course you can also replace the `dir` with `inspect.getmembers`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).