# Flask FileStorage save empty file

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms, file-storage

I am working with Flask, WTForms and Flask-WTF to save a file but the file is always store as an empty file. It doesn't show any error.

**Form:**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField

class UserForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('u', validators=[InputRequired()])
    email = StringField('e', validators=[InputRequired()])
    password = StringField('c', validators=[InputRequired()])
    signature = FileField('s')
    save = SubmitField('a')
```

**Flask Route / Function:**

```
@bp.route('/manage/user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def manage_user():
    form = UserForm()
    action = 'create'

    try:        
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            if form.save.data:
                print('request.method', request.method)
                print('request.args', request.args)
                print('request.form', request.form)
                print('request.files', request.files)
                # archivo = request.files['signature']
                # archivo = request.files.items()[0]
                archivo = form.signature.data
                print(type(archivo))
                if archivo:
                    image_data = archivo.read()
                    basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
                    filename = secure_filename(form.username.data+'.png')
                    full_dir = os.path.join(basedir, '..\\static\\img', filename)
                    print(sys.getsizeof(archivo))
                    archivo.save(full_dir) 
                return redirect(url_for('main.manage'))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    return render_template('manage_user.html', title=('Admon'), form=form, action=action)
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="POST" role="form" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.csrf_token() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-3">Firma</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            {% if action=='create' %}
            <!-- Other fields -->
            {{ form.signature(placeholder="Firma", type="file", class="form-control", accept="image/*", required="True") }}
            <img id="firmaimg" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/firma130x50_dummy.png') }}" alt="Firma" />
            {{ form.save(class="btn btn-success btn-md") }}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The print statements show this: 
[image: Print results]

The order of the prints is:

1. Request method
2. Request Arguments
3. Request Form
4. Request Files
5. Type of archivo variable

Size of archivo is always 32, it doesn't matter what image I upload, is always 32, so from that point is already empty, haven't figure out why is coming empty. I'm following the examples.

https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the size of your file is always 32 because sys.getsizeof() returns the amount of memory in bytes Python uses for that object, as explained in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof).

To print the actual file size you can use:

```
os.path.getsize('path')
```

Using it, you should see that the printed file size is effectively 0.

Secondly, by removing:

```
image_data = archivio.read()
```

you should be able to successfully save the file in the desired location.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with archivio.read().

Comment: ok, for the first part, the size, does that give me the size of the bytes object? Or is it the size of the element in the local directory?

Comment: The second part, Thank you SO much. I was just testing a lot of things and that always stayed there. You saved my life.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who has just stumbled upon this,

This error occurs when you perform save() and read() on the same file object.

I extended my research by checking 2 scenarios:

**1.read() before save()**

read() function will read the file and place the cursor at end of file. If this object is now saved, it will be empty.

**2. save() before read()**

file object becomes empty after you successfully save() the file. If you try to read it now, you will get an empty string ''

**3. Deepcopy this file object so as to perform read() and save() on separate file objects**

Not allowed. Some file types (such as FileStorage) cannot be deep copied. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696954/are-there-objects-for-which-it-is-impossible-to-create-a-deep-copy/67281630)

## Workaround

As per Naisarg's comment in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50596001/8788977):

1. save file in backend.

   `file = request.files['file']`

   `file.save(secure_filename(file.filename))`
2. Read that file.
3. Attached that file to 3rd party API.

   `r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, files={'file': (file.filename, open(file.filename, 'rb'), file.content_type)})`
4. Delete file in backend.

   `os.remove(file.filename)`