# Is it safe to make two class objects with the same name?

Tags: python, metaclass

It's possible to use `type` in Python to create a new class object, as you probably know:

```
A = type('A', (object,), {})

a = A() # create an instance of A
```

What I'm curious about is whether there's any problem with creating *different* class objects with the same name, eg, following on from the above:

```
B = type('A', (object,), {})
```

In other words, is there an issue with this second class object, `B`, having the same name as our first class object, `A`?

---

The motivation for this is that I'd like to get a clean copy of a class to apply different decorators to without using the inheritance approach described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541025/how-to-copy-a-python-class).

So I'd like to define a class normally, eg:

```
class Fruit(object):
    pass
```

and then make a fresh copy of it to play with:

```
def copy_class(cls):
    return type(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, dict(cls.__dict__))

FreshFruit = copy_class(fruit)
```

In my testing, things I do with `FreshFruit` are properly decoupled from things I do to `Fruit`.

However, I'm unsure whether I should also be mangling the name in `copy_class` in order to avoid unexpected problems.

In particular, one concern I have is that this could cause the class to be replaced in the module's dictionary, such that future imports (eg, `from module import Fruit` return the copied class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason why you can't have 2 classes with the same `__name__` in the same module if you want to and have a good reason to do so.

e.g. In your example `from module import Fruit` -- python doesn't care at all about the `__name__` of the class.  It looks in the module's globals for `Fruit` and imports what it finds there.

---

Note that, in general, this approach isn't great if you're using `super` (although the same can be said for class decorators ...):

```
class A(Base):
    def foo(self):
        super(A, self).foo()

B = copy_class(A)
```

In this case, when `B.foo` is called, it will end up calling `super(A, self)` which could lead to funky behaviour in a number of circumstances. . .

Comment: I guess that really is what my question boils down to, thanks.  So Python won't use `__name__` for anything internally?

Comment: @sapi -- Nothing "important".  Some objects might use it for `repr` or do some sort of introspection, etc.  But at the end of the day, `__name__` is a writeable attribute on a class so it can't be depended on to be the same as the "name" in whatever namespace the class lives.