# TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type. Error when calling super after metaclass creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming

Let's imagine that I make use of a library which their source code was written following this shape:

```py
class SuperLibraryDemo:
    def __init__(self, test) -> None:
        self.test = test

    def demo(self) -> str:
        return "Returning from demo method with name: %s" % self.test


class LibraryDemo(SuperLibraryDemo):
    def __init__(self, test: str = "something") -> None:
        super(LibraryDemo, self).__init__(test)
        print("At LibraryDemo __init__ method: This should have been skipped")

    def demo(self) -> None:
        super().demo()
```

Remember that is a library. I not supposed to tweak it source code for my needs.
However I need switch the inner code which `__init__` method calls within the `LibraryDemo` for reasons beyond the scope of this question.

With this goal in mind, I decide to code a `CustomLibraryDemo` with the help of a metaclass, as this:

```py
class MetaDemo(type):
    def __new__(mcs, class_name: str, bases: Tuple[Type, ...], class_dict: Dict[str, Any]):
        basis = bases[0]
        c_attrs = dict(basis.__dict__)
        prior_c_process_bases = basis.__base__
        c_attrs["__init__"] = lambda self, settings: prior_c_process_bases.__init__(self, settings)
        new_bases = types.new_class(basis.__qualname__, basis.__bases__,
                                    exec_body=lambda np: MetaDemo.populate_class_dict(np, c_attrs))
        return super(MetaDemo, mcs).__new__(mcs, class_name, (new_bases,), class_dict)

    @staticmethod
    def populate_class_dict(namespace: Dict[str, Any], attr: Dict[str, Any]) -> None:
        for key, value in attr.items():
            namespace[key] = value

class CustomLibraryDemo(LibraryDemo, metaclass=MetaDemo):
    def __init__(self, test: Optional[str] = None) -> None:
        super(CustomLibraryDemo, self).__init__(test)
        print("At CustomDemo __init__ method: This message should appear")

    def test(self) -> None:
        print("In test method at CustomLibraryDemo class: %s" % self.test)
```

Though this approach at the first sight seem to work for me, I get an error when I call `CustomLibraryDemo().demo()` saying:

```py
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

Why that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not need a custom metaclass; instead, just adjust the arguments to `super`.

```
class CustomLibraryDemo(LibraryDemo):
    def __init__(self, test: Optional[str] = None) -> None:
        super(LibraryDemo, self).__init__(test)
        print("At CustomDemo __init__ method: This message should appear")

    def test(self) -> None:
        print("In test method at CustomLibraryDemo class: %s" % self.test)
```

Using `LibraryDemo` instead of `CustomerLibraryDemo` causes `super` to start further along the MRO when deciding which class to use next.

```
% python3 tmp.py
At CustomDemo __init__ method: This message should appear
```

Comment: Yes, really simple solution. Even thought my approach works, it is a dramatic over-engineering solution.

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40818991/python-3-super-and-metaprogramming) solves my issue.
For my case, changing `basis.__bases__` for `bases` argument on `__new__` method signature fix the issue.
This way, the syntax on `new_bases` variable turns out to be:

```py
new_bases = types.new_class(basis.__qualname__, bases,
                                    exec_body=lambda np: MetaDemo.populate_class_dict(np, c_attrs))
```

By the way, for this code can be simplified to:

```py
new_bases = type(basis.__qualname__, bases, c_attrs)
```

Dropping the `populate_class_dict` metaclass method.