# Is it possible to properly copy a class using type

Tags: python, types, metaclass

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13379957/2988730), a class object `cls` can be replicated with

```
cls_copy = type('cls_copy', cls.__bases__, dict(cls.__dict__))
```

This works perfectly for most normal cases. It does *not* work when the metaclass of `cls` is not `type`. My initial naive fix was to do

```
cls_copy = type(cls)('cls_copy', cls.__bases__, dict(cls.__dict__))
```

However, this is simply pointless. There is no way to know what a metaclass does, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49140775/2988730) to a related question points out, how it transforms the input dictionary, what additional keywords it requires, etc.

The original use of `type` is almost good enough with a couple of minor exceptions:

1. The `__dict__` created by metaclasses that do not end up calling `type.__new__` may be of a different type than the usual proxy object.
2. Classes extending the copy will not have the correct metaclass, which may cause unexpected behavior.
3. Any properties or other data descriptors defined in the original metaclass will no longer be available on the class object.

I am willing to ignore item #1. It is a corner case that I am willing to document away should I find a viable solution to the other items. Items #2 and #3 can be solved if it were possible to change the metaclass of the copy. I tried (again, naively)

```
cls_copy = type('cls_copy', cls.__bases__, dict(cls.__dict__),
                metaclass=type(cls))
```

This just raised a `TypeError`, as could be expected:

```
TypeError: __init_subclass__() takes no keyword arguments
```

This makes sense in light of the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types):

> Like its identity, an object’s type is also unchangeable. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13379957/2988730)

However, the [footnote](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#id8) states that

> It *is* possible in some cases to change an object’s type, under certain controlled conditions. It generally isn’t a good idea though, since it can lead to some very strange behaviour if it is handled incorrectly.

What are the conditions under which it is possible to change an object's type, specifically that of a class? Is this one of those cases, and if so, how?

**Note**

I am aware that `copy.deepcopy` and inheritance are viable alternatives here. For the purpose of this question, I wish to ignore those alternatives and stick with using `type`-related techniques.

Comment: `type.__new__(type(cls), cls.__bases__, ...)` might work. Am I missing any corner cases with that?

Comment: @internet_user. None that I am not OK with :) thanks very much for that. Would you be willing to write that up for formal points?

Comment: @internet_user. I half-expected the answer to be just "no", so it's awesome that I missed something so simple.

Comment: Oops, yeah I forgot the name argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `type.__new__(type(cls), cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, dict(cls.__dict__))`. This uses the normal `type` creation process, but creates an instance of `type(cls)` instead of `type`.

As for the `__metaclass__` issue, I think that is because `__metaclass__` is usually what is called, so `type` can't use it.

Comment: Added name in :)

Comment: Docs say "Any *other* keyword arguments that are specified in the class definition are passed through to all metaclass operations described below." [Emphasis mine]. This implies that the metaclass keyword just doesn't figure outside the interpreter.

Comment: Part of the problem is that I wrote `__metaclass__` instead of `metaclass`, but the error is the same either way.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I explicitly added in `dict(cls.__dict__)`. Without the `dict`, it will raise an error `TypeError: type.__new__() argument 3 must be dict, not mappingproxy`, so I though it would be worth mentioning.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine.