# How to override module name (__name__)?

Tags: python, class, oop, global-variables, python-module

I have two classes in separate files, **a.py** and **b.py**.

```py
# a.py
import logging

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class A:
    def name(self):
        # Do something
        LOG.debug("Did something") # LOG reads __name__ and print it.
```

I can not modify **a.py** in any way.

```py
# b.py
import a

class B(A):
    pass
```

The log output is:

```
DEBUG:<TIME> called in a, Did something
```

I want to change `__name__` so that a child class's call should log `called in b`.

My project logs its module name as part of the output. However, when I inherit a class and call the parent class method, I cannot know it is called from `A` or `B` because it only shows the parent's module name. How can I change it? Or, some other way to avoid this?

Comment: Surely you should be referring to `self.__name__` not `__name__`?

Comment: @smci. No, OP wants the module namespace

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks.
@smci I want to solve without changing log in logging which reads `__name__` of module.

Comment: It seems like trying to alter `__name__` which is part of python's module import system is a bad way to get functionality like this. Why not just use a property on the instance or class?

Comment: @Mark. It's not part of the import system exactly. It's not used once it's set as far as I'm aware. The problem is that `A` is unalterable.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I guess I would be more precise to say it is part of the *expected* module system, in that anyone reading your code would expect certain conventions when using `__name__`.  For example the convention of using `logging.getLogger(__name__)`. I think tampering with this violates the principle of least surprise.

Comment: @Mark. I agree. But you can alter other things in a careful manner. My answer suggests an alternative that does not directly violate least surprise.

Comment: @osflw. Let me know if my edit is acceptable. You shouldn't leave "Update" or "Edit" in your question except in very rare circumstances. The idea that your prior work is valuable and shouldn't be clobbered by improvements is totally false. There's an edit history we could look at it we wanted to see a more incomplete version of your question.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for your editing. It's more readable. I thought I should leave my edit history for the answers made before it.

Comment: @osflw. Only if your edit fundamentally invalidates some answers is that a valid concern. In this case, it's something that clearly should have been mentioned in the question to begin with.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do it, but it's more involved than you might think.

Where does the name `__name__` come from? The answer is that it's a global variable. This is to be expected, since the global namespace is the module namespace. For example:

```
>>> globals()['__name__']
'__main__'
```

If you look up callables in the [Standard Type Hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) of python's [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) documentation, you will find that a function's `__globals__` attribute is read-only. That means that the function `A.name` will always look up its global attributes in the namespace of module `a` (not that the module namespace itself is read-only).

The only way to alter globals for a function is to copy the function object. This has been hashed out on Stack Overflow at least a couple of times:

- [How to create a copy of a python function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13503079/2988730)
- [How can I make a deepcopy of a function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6527633/2988730)

Copying classes has come up as well:

- [Is it possible to properly copy a class using type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49157255/298873)

**Solution 1**

I've gone ahead and implemented both techniques in a utility library I made called [haggis](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Specifically, [`haggis.objects.copy_class`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#haggis.objects.copy_class) will do what you want:

```
from haggis.objects import copy_class
import a

class B(copy_class(A, globals(), __name__)):
    pass
```

This will copy `A`. All function code and non-function attributes will be referenced directly. However, function objects will have the updated `__globals__` and `__module__` attributes applied.

The major problem with this method is that it breaks your intended inheritance hierarchy slightly. Functionally, you won't see a difference, but `issubclass(b.B, a.A)` will no longer be true.

**Solution 2 (probably the best one)**

I can see how it would be a bit cumbersome to copy *all* the methods of `A` and break the inheritance hierarchy by doing this. Luckily, there is another method, [`haggis.objects.copy_func`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#haggis.objects.copy_func), which can help you copy just the `name` method out of `A`:

```
from haggis.objects import copy_func
import a

class B(A):
    name = copy_func(A.name, globals(), __name__)
```

This solution is a bit more robust, because copying classes is much more finicky than copying functions in python. It's fairly efficient because both versions of `name` will actually share the same code object: only the metadata, including `__globals__`, will be different.

**Solution 3**

You have a much simpler solution available if you can alter `A` ever so slightly. Every (normal) class in python has a `__module__` attribute that is the `__name__` attribute of the module where it was defined.

You can just rewrite `A` as

```
class A:
    def name(self):
        # Do something
        print("Did in %s" % self.__module__)
```

Using `self.__module__` instead of `__name__` is roughly analogous to using `type(self)` instead of `__class__`.

**Solution 4**

Another simple idea is to properly override `A.name`:

```
class B(A):
    def name(self):
        # Do something
        LOG.debug("Did something")
```

Of course I can see how this would not work well if `# Do something` is a complex task that is not implemented elsewhere. It's probably much more efficient to just copy the function object directly out of `A`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed solution. Because I cannot change `a.py` (added in the text), according to your answer, I have to copy all methods in A to B.

Comment: @osflw. Yes, but I already wrote the function for that, which is not very long: https://github.com/madphysicist/haggis/blob/f7dacb0ce6acec5d8665ea7b85d6866174da5849/src/haggis/objects.py#L145

Comment: @osflw. You can avoid copying *all* the methods. The problem is that `A` is not implemented for the flexibility you want, so you can either re-implement it, or work around it. You aren't being given the choice.

Comment: @osflw. I've updated my answer. You only really need to copy one method. It's like a more efficient form of overriding: the code object will be shared, and pretty much only the `__globals__` and `__module__` attributes are changed, which is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point. It was very helpful. I think the fastest solution is overriding the methods that use LOG.

Comment: @osflw. Feel free to select the answer whenever you're ready

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution:

Try using [`inspect.stack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect%20stack#inspect.stack):

```
import inspect
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def name(self):
        # Do something
        print("Did in %s" % inspect.stack()[1].filename.rpartition('/')[-1][:-3])
```

And now running `b.py` would output:

```
Did in b
```

#### Explanation:

`inspect` can inspect live objects in python scripts, as metioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect%20stack#inspect.stack):

> Return a list of frame records for the caller’s stack. The first entry in the returned list represents the caller; the last entry represents the outermost call on the stack.

Also it mentioned that it outputs a `NamedTuple` like:

> `FrameInfo(frame, filename, lineno, function, code_context, index)`

So we could just get the live filename with indexing the second element of this tuple, that would give the full path, so we would have to split it up the path and extract the filename from the full path using `str.rpartition`.

## Edit:

For not editing `a.py`, you could only try:

### `b.py`:

```
import inspect
exec(inspect.getsource(__import__('a')))
class B(A):
    pass
```

And it would give:

```
Did in b
```

Comment: You were on the right track: use properties of the defining class instead of A, but there is a muuuuch simpler way to do it. Not that my original solution is particularly simple :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist hmm with `inspect`?

Comment: See my updated answer. With `self.__module__`. It's a trivial change to `A`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Tested with `self.__module__` but it gave `__main__`?

Comment: Because you did not place your classes into separate files like OP did. `self.__module__` is going to be `__name__` without the hard-coding.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but please assume that `a.py` cannot be changed. I added some more detail in the text.

Comment: @osflw Well then I am actually not sure if that's possible...

Comment: @osflw. In that case, I'd argue that my function is the only way to go about it: just extend a copy of `A` which has all the same actual code but different global bindings.

Comment: @osflw Edited my answer with something that works without editing `a`, even though that isn't very safe and efficient

Comment: @osflw Check the **Edit:** part

Comment: I upvoted. I didn't try yet, I already overrode them in child class. Thanks for your help.