# Making copies of built-ins classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, copy, cpython

I'm trying to write function which creates classes from classes without modifying original one.

Simple solution (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13379957/5997596))

```
def class_operator(cls):
    namespace = dict(vars(cls))
    ...  # modifying namespace
    return type(cls.__qualname__, cls.__bases__, namespace)
```

works fine except `type` itself:

```
>>> class_operator(type)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: type __qualname__ must be a str, not getset_descriptor
```

Tested on **Python 3.2**-**Python 3.6**.

(I know that in current version modification of mutable attributes in `namespace` object will change original class, but it is not the case)

## Update

Even if we remove `__qualname__` parameter from `namespace` if there is any

```
def class_operator(cls):
    namespace = dict(vars(cls))
    namespace.pop('__qualname__', None)
    return type(cls.__qualname__, cls.__bases__, namespace)
```

resulting object doesn't behave like original `type`

```
>>> type_copy = class_operator(type)
>>> type_copy is type
False
>>> type_copy('')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor '__init__' for 'type' objects doesn't apply to 'type' object
>>> type_copy('empty', (), {})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor '__init__' for 'type' objects doesn't apply to 'type' object
```

## Why?

Can someone explain what mechanism in **Python** internals prevents copying `type` class (and many other built-in classes).

Comment: I would imagine there are all sorts of corner cases that prevent `dict(vars(cls))` from providing a suitable basis for *duplicating* a class. What is your use case that you need a copy of a type rather than just subclassing it?

Comment: Note that you aren't modifying the original type; you are just making a poor copy of the original. Are you expecting `type_copy is type` to be true? That *never* will be, unless `class_operator` simply returns `type` itself.

Comment: @chepner: i am waiting `type_copy is type` to be `False` (i know what [operator `is`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is) does)

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `type` has a `__qualname__` in its `__dict__`, which is a property (i.e. a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)) rather than a string:

```
>>> type.__qualname__
'type'
>>> vars(type)['__qualname__']
<attribute '__qualname__' of 'type' objects>
```

And trying to assign a non-string to the `__qualname__` of a class throws an exception:

```
>>> class C: pass
...
>>> C.__qualname__ = 'Foo'  # works
>>> C.__qualname__ = 3  # doesn't work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only assign string to C.__qualname__, not 'int'
```

This is why it's necessary to remove the `__qualname__` from the `__dict__`.

As for the reason why your `type_copy` isn't callable: This is because `type.__call__` rejects anything that isn't a subclass of `type`. This is true for both the 3-argument form:

```
>>> type.__call__(type, 'x', (), {})
<class '__main__.x'>
>>> type.__call__(type_copy, 'x', (), {})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor '__init__' for 'type' objects doesn't apply to 'type' object
```

As well as the single-argument form, which actually only works with `type` as its first argument:

```
>>> type.__call__(type, 3)
<class 'int'>
>>> type.__call__(type_copy, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: type.__new__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

This isn't easy to circumvent. Fixing the 3-argument form is simple enough: We make the copy an empty subclass of `type`.

```
>>> type_copy = type('type_copy', (type,), {})
>>> type_copy('MyClass', (), {})
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
```

But the single-argument form of `type` is much peskier, since it only works if the first argument is `type`. We can implement a custom `__call__` method, but that method must be written in the metaclass, which means `type(type_copy)` will be different from `type(type)`.

```
>>> class TypeCopyMeta(type):
...     def __call__(self, *args):
...         if len(args) == 1:
...             return type(*args)
...         return super().__call__(*args)
... 
>>> type_copy = TypeCopyMeta('type_copy', (type,), {})
>>> type_copy(3)  # works
<class 'int'>
>>> type_copy('MyClass', (), {})  # also works
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
>>> type(type), type(type_copy)  # but they're not identical
(<class 'type'>, <class '__main__.TypeCopyMeta'>)
```

---

There are two reasons why `type` is so difficult to copy:

1. It's implemented in C. You'll run into similar problems if you try to copy other builtin types like `int` or `str`.
2. The fact that `type` is an instance of *itself*:

   ```
   >>> type(type)
   <class 'type'>
   ```

   This is something that's usually not possible. It blurs the line between class and instance. It's a chaotic accumulation of instance and class attributes. This is why `__qualname__` is a string when accessed as `type.__qualname__` but a descriptor when accessed as `vars(type)['__qualname__']`.

---

As you can see, it's not possible to make a perfect copy of `type`. Each implementation has different tradeoffs.

The easy solution is to make a subclass of `type`, which doesn't support the single-argument `type(some_object)` call:

```
import builtins

def copy_class(cls):
    # if it's a builtin class, copy it by subclassing
    if getattr(builtins, cls.__name__, None) is cls:
        namespace = {}
        bases = (cls,)
    else:
        namespace = dict(vars(cls))
        bases = cls.__bases__

    cls_copy = type(cls.__name__, bases, namespace)
    cls_copy.__qualname__ = cls.__qualname__
    return cls_copy
```

The elaborate solution is to make a custom metaclass:

```
import builtins

def copy_class(cls):
    if cls is type:
        namespace = {}
        bases = (cls,)

        class metaclass(type):
            def __call__(self, *args):
                if len(args) == 1:
                    return type(*args)
                return super().__call__(*args)

        metaclass.__name__ = type.__name__
        metaclass.__qualname__ = type.__qualname__
    # if it's a builtin class, copy it by subclassing
    elif getattr(builtins, cls.__name__, None) is cls:
        namespace = {}
        bases = (cls,)
        metaclass = type
    else:
        namespace = dict(vars(cls))
        bases = cls.__bases__
        metaclass = type

    cls_copy = metaclass(cls.__name__, bases, namespace)
    cls_copy.__qualname__ = cls.__qualname__
    return cls_copy
```

Comment: thanks and please check **Update** part of the question

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Yeah, I didn't notice the update while I was busy writing my answer... gimme a sec

Comment: it's close, but `type_copy('')` will give us `TypeError: type.__new__() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Updated.

Comment: This is still going to fail on pretty much any built-in type, not just `type`. It'll fail especially hard for `type`, but it won't work right for other types, either. For example, if you try to copy `int` this way, instances of the result don't support arithmetic, hashing, or pretty much any of the functionality of `int`. The dict-level copy just can't reach deep enough into the C to copy what needs to be copied.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the code to copy builtin classes by subclassing. It's not perfect, but it'll have to do.