# Creating a copy of a python list out of class elements

Tags: python, list, class, deep-copy

I'm working on a script processing computed strains/deformations for multiple nodes of a finite element analysis (FEA). There are multiple solutions for different, positive input torques. I want to extrapolate this data and simulate the results for negative torques. Whilst doing that the original data changes.

As we are not directly changing any of the original values I think it must be accessed by reference through the function extrapolating the FEA. I've been trying `copy.deepcopy`, but figured over multiple threads that this does not copy class structures. In [other threads it was recommended to inherit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541025/how-to-copy-a-python-class) but I'm struggling adapting it to my case.

The following code is inside the class containing all nodes on the same radius of the object. All nodes are in a list `self._nodes` sorted by their angle. Each node has the strains for all torque levels.

```
class RadialNodeContainer:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self._r = radius
        self._nodes = []
    def compute_negatives_radial_container(self): # ... see below

class Node:
    def __init__(self, node_id, x, y, z,
                 strain_0nm, strain_100nm, strain_204nm, strain_369nm):
        self._coordinate = Coordinate(x, y, z)
        self._torque_levels = [strain_0nm, strain_100nm,
                               strain_204nm, strain_369nm]
    def get_all_strains_complete(self):
        return copy.deepcopy(self._torque_levels)

class Strain:
    def __init__(self, torque_nm, exx, exy, eyy):
        self._torque = torque_nm
        self._exx = exx
        self._exy = exy
        self._eyy = eyy
```

The function which causes unwanted changes the original data:

```
def compute_negatives_radial_container(self):
    points_per_360deg = len(self._nodes)
    jj = points_per_360deg
    corresponding_node_strains = None
    for ii in range(points_per_360deg):
        jj -= 1
        # Mistake is expected below here
        corresponding_node_strains = copy.deepcopy(
                         self._nodes[jj].get_all_strains_complete())                      
        for kk in range(len(corresponding_node_strains)):
            torque = corresponding_node_strains[kk].get_torque_level()
            if torque != 0:
                exx, exy, eyy = corresponding_node_strains[kk].get_raw_strains()
                calculated_negative_strain = Strain(torque_nm=-torque,
                                                    exx=exx,
                                                    exy=-exy,
                                                    eyy=eyy)
                self._nodes[ii].add_torque_level(calculated_negative_strain)
```

I thought of creating a `deepcopy` of the list of strain elements (`Node -> self._torque_level`). Originally this list looks like `[Strain(0Nm), Strain(100Nm), ...]`. But I can't wrap my head around what part(s) of the code I have to adapt to allow passing a copy of the class instances.

Comment: Can't you simply add a method to Strain to deal with a negative value? Then when later referenced use either a switch in the class or a different method.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate.  I will expand on this if I have time and it's what the OP is looking for.

I would also recommend using numpy for your arrays rather than lists as mumpy is much faster.

```
class Strain:
    def __init__(self, torque_nm, exx, exy, eyy):
        self._torque = torque_nm
        self._exx = exx
        self._exy = exy
        self._eyy = eyy
        self._neg = False

    def setNeg(self, neg):
        self._neg = neg

    @propery
    def torque(self):
        return _torque if not self._neg else -self.torque

    @propery
    def exx(self):
        return _exx

    @propery
    def exy(self):
        return _exy if not self._neg else -self._exy

    @propery
    def eyy(self):
        return _eyy
```

Comment: Thank you for the proposition. The negatives are extrapolated of strains of nodes at a different location (mirrored over the x-axis) and can't be generated of the strains of the same node.
In other words: we take `self._nodes[jj]`-values for the negatives at `self._nodes[ii]`. I thus don't think this approach would work. Thank you for introducing me to @property, very neat!

Comment: So do the same thing but on the array of data rather than the array points.  Have a 'strain_array' class and have it mutate it's outputs based on some switch.  Create a subclass of some collection class or use __iter__() special method on your own class.