Copying a class object in Python
Suppose I have a complicated class with lots of methods. In particular it is callable via a __call__ member. I would like to have an object from the exact same class, but not callable and not with __call__ at all in fact, because some introspection tool would detect it and this is not wanted.
The obvious solution is to make a new class, copying the code from the original one, and removing __call__. But is there a way to do this programmatically?
I went from:
import copy

class A:
    def __call__(self):
       print(self, "CALLED")

B = copy.deepcopy(A) # for some reason it is not a real copy...
del B.__call__ # seems to work, but also removes `__call__` from A !!!

a=A()
a() # TypeError: 'A' is not callable

# this was the more surprising to me...

to:
class B(A):
    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if attr == "__call__":
            raise AttributeError(attr)
        return super().__getattribute__(attr)

b = B()
b.__call__ # raises attribute error, nice
b() # still calls A.__call__... WTF!

passing through many attempts.
Is there a way? How to get a true copy of a class object (not an instance) in Python?
I checked existing Q&A, but none seem to address this particular issue. I also thought about extracting source code, and removing the __call__ method from the string and having it re-evaluated.

Why not using inheritance ?

I need the child class to not have __call__ - that is, deleting a parent method (in the case of inheritance). You cannot. So I thought, let's copy the class, delete its __call__ and make an object from it... But I stumbled on the unexpected

"For some reason" - what reason? It's very hard to suggest possible solutions without understanding the context and constraints.

Ok I removed "for some reason", edited post

Couldn't you go the other way around? Define B as the base class, define A(B) (A inherits from B) and implement its __call__

Just removing "for some reason" is not actually the same as including the reason.

Maybe this post would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541025/how-to-copy-a-class

You can use type() to dynamically create a new class without the specified method:
def remove_method_from_class(cls, new_class_name: str, method_name: str):
    attrs = {k: v for k, v in cls.__dict__.items() if k != method_name}
    return type(new_class_name, cls.__bases__, attrs)

class A:
    def __call__(self):
        print(self, "CALLED")
    
    def other_method(self):
        print("Other method")

B = remove_method_from_class(A, "B", "__call__")

a = A()
a()  # This should work

b = B()
# b()  # This raises a TypeError because B is not callable
print(hasattr(b, '__call__'))  # Prints False
print(hasattr(a, '__call__'))  # Prints True
b.other_method()  # This should still work


You could use a metaclass, which allows you control how a class is created:
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
        if not clsname.startswith('A'):
            dct.pop('__call__', None)
        return super(Meta, cls).__new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct)

class A(metaclass=Meta):
    def __call__(self):
        print(f"__called__: {self.__class__.__name__}")

class B(metaclass=Meta):
    pass

class C(metaclass=Meta):
    pass


for _cls in [A, B, C]:
    try:
        _cls()()
    except:
        print(f"{_cls} has no __call__ method")

Out:
__called__: A
<class '__main__.B'> has no __call__ method
<class '__main__.C'> has no __call__ method

