# Calculate cosine distance between embeddings on Matlab

Tags: python, matlab

I have a few lines of code where I have a `torch tensor` (`200.000 x 512`) and I want to calculate the cosine distance between each of those embeddings.

Right now, I'm doing:

```
similarity = (image_features.cpu() @ image_features.cpu().T).squeeze()
```

But it takes too long. Maybe matlab is much faster. Does anyone can tell me how to do it there? (Convert my tensor to .mat file + code)

Answer (score 0):

You can [convert your `torch tensor` into a `numpy array`](https://sparrow.dev/pytorch-numpy-conversion/),
then [save that to a `.mat` with scipy's `savemat()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html).

```py
from scipy.io import savemat

# to numpy array
arr = tensor.numpy()
# to .mat, needs second input to be a dict type
savemat("filename.mat", {'a': arr})
```

However, [MATLAB isn't always faster than Python (Numpy)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18517922/5675094); especially when doing matrix multiplications, since Numpy itself is also highly optimized. So I believe that trying the same matrix multiplication on MATLAB won't speed things up. In fact, it might be faster to do the calculation in pytorch if you have a GPU available.

Perhaps a more relevant question here is [how to calculate the cosine similarity of large datasets?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80282/how-do-i-deal-with-large-data-similarity-computation)