# binary input with an ASCII text header, read from stdin

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, binary, ascii

I want to read a binary [PNM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) image file from stdin.  The file contains a header which is encoded as ASCII text, and a payload which is binary.  As a simplified example of reading the header, I have created the following snippet:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import sys
header = sys.stdin.readline()
print("header=["+header.strip()+"]")
```

I run it as "test.py" (from a Bash shell), and it works fine in this case:

```
$ printf "P5 1 1 255\n\x41" |./test.py 
header=[P5 1 1 255]
```

However, a small change in the binary payload breaks it:

```
$ printf "P5 1 1 255\n\x81" |./test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 3, in <module>
    header = sys.stdin.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 313, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 11: invalid start byte
```

Is there an easy way to make this work in Python 3?

Comment: did you try to change the input encoding ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16549381/4954037

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: Thanks for the hint.  The approach indicated there did lead me to one possible solution -- although it is a bit of a hack to apply Unicode decoding to arbitrary binary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html), it is possible to read binary data (as type `bytes`) from stdin with `sys.stdin.buffer.read()`:

> To write or read binary data from/to the standard streams, use the
>   underlying binary buffer object. For example, to write bytes to
>   stdout, use sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'abc').

So this is one direction that you can take -- read the data in binary mode.  `readline()` and various other functions still work.  Once you have captured the ASCII string, it can be converted to text, using `decode('ASCII')`, for additional text-specific processing.

Alternatively, you can use `io.TextIOWrapper()` to indicate the use of the `latin-1` character set on the input stream.  With this, the implicit decode operation will essentially be a pass-through operation -- so the data will be of type `str` (which represent text), but the data is represented with a 1-to-1 mapping from the binary (although it could be using more than one storage byte per input byte).

Here's code that works in either mode:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import sys, io

BINARY=True ## either way works

if BINARY: istream = sys.stdin.buffer
else:      istream = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdin.buffer,encoding='latin-1')

header = istream.readline()
if BINARY: header = header.decode('ASCII')
print("header=["+header.strip()+"]")

payload = istream.read()
print("len="+str(len(payload)))
for i in payload: print( i if BINARY else ord(i) )
```

Test every possible 1-pixel payload with the following Bash command:

```
for i in $(seq 0 255) ; do printf "P5 1 1 255\n\x$(printf %02x $i)" |./test.py ; done
```

Comment: The hack of using `latin-1` as a conduit for binary data works because it is [8-bit clean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_clean), whereas [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is not.

Answer (score 2):

To read binary data, you should use a binary stream e.g., using [`TextIOBase.detach()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.detach):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

sys.stdin = sys.stdin.detach() # convert to binary stream
header = sys.stdin.readline().decode('ascii') # b'\n'-terminated
print(header, end='')
print(repr(sys.stdin.read()))
```