# Determine the endianness of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, endianness

I have a `numpy.array` and I want to find out what endianness is used in the underlying representation.

A `byteorder` property is documented [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.byteorder.html), but none of the given examples show it being used with an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`byteorder` is a data type objects [`dtype`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) attribute so you need to do this:

```
In [10]: import numpy as np

In [11]: arr = np.array([1,2,3])

In [12]: arr.dtype.byteorder
Out[12]: '='
```