# numpy.array of an "I;16" Image file

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, tiff

I want to use TIFF images to effectively save large arrays of measurement data. With setting them to mode="I;16" (corresponding to my 16 bit data range), they yield 2MB files (~1000x1000 "pixel"). Which is good.

However I am having troubles reconverting them into arrays when it comes to analysing them. For 32bit data (-> "I") the numpy.array command works fine. In case of "I;16" the result is a 0D numpy array with the TIFF as the [0,0] entry.

Is there a way to get that to work? I would really like to avoid using 32bit images, as I don't need the range and it doubles the HDD space required (lots and lots of those measurements planned...)

Comment: Can you show us the code how you load the image?  Are you using PIL's `Image` class?

Comment: I use the Image class, and to load the images I simply use Image.open("im.tif")

Comment: PIL bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247371/python-and-16-bit-tiff

Comment: Thanks for the hint mankoff, but I still don't quite get it. So I have to convert it to 32bit -> mode 'I' right? When I do that and load the result into a numpy array I get wrong data (a full uint16 scale, from 0 to 65000something). I don't want to work with images, I need to convert the TIFF grayscale into the actual values! Is the answer in there?

Comment: Maybe I should elaborate what it is that I am doing here: I get the data in a numpy array, rescale it a bit, to use the 16bit dataspace better (log10, linear expansion), round and set it to numpy.int16. My range in the array is about -20000 < x < +20000 then. Generate my Image with PIL.fromarray (automatic mode "I;16") and save it. Those are the images/datamaps I will open and reconvert later on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work (pillow/PIL solution, slow for 16-bit image, see below).

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(0,2**16-1,(1000,1000))
im = Image.fromarray(data)
im.save('test.tif')

im2 = Image.open('test.tif')
data2 = np.array(im2.getdata()).reshape(im2.size[::-1])
```

Another solution using [tifffile](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/tifffile.py.html) by C. Gohlke (very fast):

```
import tifffile

fp = r'path\to\image\image.tif'

with tifffile.TIFFfile(fp) as tif:
    data = tif.asarray()
```

Comment: I managed to somehow not notice your answer before I posted mine.  I agree, this is the best workaround, but I think you need to reorder the size of the reshape... It should be `...reshape(im2.size[::-1])`

Comment: Right! im.size => (width, height) but we want our numpy array to be in (height, width). Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Using a relatively modern version of PIL (2.6.1), this doesn't seem to work. The fromarray() method throws an exception `Cannot handle this data type`. Thanks for the tifffile reference though, I'll try that.

Answer (score 3):

You could use GDAL + Numpy/Scipy to read raster images with 16bit channel data:

```
import gdal
tif = gdal.Open('path.tif')
arr = tif.ReadAsArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert an (ImageJ) TIFF to an 8 bit numpy array

```
im = numpy.array(Image.open('my.tiff'))
n = (im / numpy.amax(im) * 255).astype(numpy.uint8)
```