# Can't apply image filters on 16-bit TIFs in PIL

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I try to apply image filters using python's [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/). The code is straight forward:

```
im = Image.open(fnImage)
im = im.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
```

This code works as expected on PNGs, JPGs and on 8-bit TIFs. However, when I try to apply this code on 16-bit TIFs, I get the following error

```
ValueError: image has wrong mode
```

Note that PIL was able to load, resize and save 16-bit TIFs without complains, so I assume that this problem is filter-related. However, [ImageFilter documentation](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagefilter.htm) says nothing about 16-bit support

Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Not very helpful, but I'd wager the blur filter just doesn't support it. Not even Photoshop supports every operation in 16-bit mode (sadly.)

Comment: @Skurmedel ImageFilter documentation says nothing about 16-bit support, which makes me think that this is a solvable problem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your TIFF image's mode is most likely a "I;16".
In the current version of ImageFilter, kernels can only be applied to
 "L" and "RGB" images (see source of ImageFilter.py)

Try converting first to another mode:

```
im.convert('L')
```

If it fails, try:

```
im.mode = 'I'
im = im.point(lambda i:i*(1./256)).convert('L').filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
```

Remark: Possible duplicate from [Python and 16 Bit Tiff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247371/python-and-16-bit-tiff)

Comment: If you run into this problem when trying to do logical operators from `ImageChops` then you should use `im.convert("1")`.

Comment: In case it's not obvious: note that `L` and `I` modes are both 8-bit modes (ref: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html#modes) and so the code shown here will reduce the depth of your image from 16 bit to 8 bit.

Answer (score 0):

To move ahead, try using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), look for PythonMagick hooks to the program. On the command prompt, you can use `convert.exe image-16.tiff -blur 2x2 output.tiff`. Didn't manage to install PythonMagick in my windows OS as the source needs compiling.