# DICOM to TIFF inverted LUT ... Python & PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, dicom, imaging, pydicom

I am using the **frombuffer** command to save DICOM image data as TIFF images. But somehwere throughout this process, the image intensities are inverted (inverted LUT). Any idea on how to overcome this?

I have tried using the **ImageOps.invert** function from PIL, but if gives me "not supported for this image mode" error.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import dicom
import Image
import PIL.ImageOps

meta=dicom.read_file("DicomImage.dcm") 
imHeight=meta.Rows
imWidth=meta.Columns 
imSize=(imWidth,imHeight)
TT=Image.frombuffer("L",imSize,meta.PixelData,"raw","L",0,1)
TT.save("testOUTPUT.tiff","TIFF",compression="none")
```

Any guidance is appreciated ...
Python 2.7
PIL 1.1.7
Pydicom 0.9.6

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `""` for the raw mode, you should be using one of the mode strings [from the documentation](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/decoder.htm). Try `"L"` or `"L;I"`, one or the other should be correct.

Comment: I have tried both, but the I need to maintain the 16bit status of the image intensities.

Comment: @Masrawy, look at this link and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247371/python-and-16-bit-tiff