# Convert tiff (I;16) to JPG with PIL/pillow

Tags: python, jpeg, tiff, python-imaging-library

I have a problem converting a tiff image from a microscope to a jpeg, which should be shown within a web application.
I tried the following:

```
image = Image.open(file_name)
image.convert(mode="RGB")
image.save('my.jpeg')

>>IOError: cannot write mode I;16 as JPEG
```

Anybody has some experience in converting 16-bit TIFF files to jpegs...
I have linked such a file below.
Thanks for your help!

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B04N02JqhWJOWjBPY1RRZkIwbTg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug. Here is a workaround:

```
import Image
image = Image.open("Fredy1_002.tif")
image.mode = 'I'
image.point(lambda i:i*(1./256)).convert('L').save('my.jpeg')
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7248480/839338

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfect and saved my day :)

Comment: hey, I am having the same problem! if I plot the image with matplotlib using `ax.imshow(image.point(lambda i:i*(1./256)).convert('L'), cmap=plt.cm.bone)` I can see the image, but the file `'my.jpeg'` it is a black image! can you please help?

Comment: I have created this new stackoverflow question with more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56956198/pil-converting-from-i16-to-jpeg-produce-white-image

Comment: I'm guessing this answer was copied from Mark Ransom's identical answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247371/python-and-16-bit-tiff

Comment: I have used Pillow for years and PIL before that. I have many code snippets in my code base which I often use to answer questions. I am uncertain of where these originated from as I don't keep track of the source unless it is licenced. I generally link to answers if I find them on the web but if I find a snippet in my code base I just post it, apologies to Mark Ransom if my snippet came from his post originally.