# PIL converting from I;16 to JPEG produce white image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, jpeg, tiff

I am having a problem converting an image I;16 to JPEG with PIL.
My original image can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/160Vj-tVLCBuhp4u4pabcnQ0Rte0nWyf4/view?usp=sharing) (as pickle).
The original image comes from a DICOM file.
Here is the code to try:

```
import pickle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

ims = pickle.load(open("pixel_array.pickle", "rb"))

img = Image.fromarray(ims)
print(img.mode)
rgb_im = img.convert("RGB")
print(rgb_im.mode)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
ax.imshow(rgb_im, cmap=plt.cm.bone)
fig.show()
```

Unfortunately the image is completely white, while it should be a chest x-ray scan image.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43978819/convert-tiff-i16-to-jpg-with-pil-pillow) other stackoverflow question, and with the following

```
ims = pickle.load(open("pixel_array.pickle", "rb"))

img = Image.fromarray(ims)
print(img.mode)

img.mode = 'I'
rgb_im = img.point(lambda i:i*(1./256)).convert('L')
rgb_im.save('my.jpeg')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
ax.imshow(rgb_im, cmap=plt.cm.bone)
fig.show()
```

I am able to visualise the image, but unfortunately `my.jpeg` is a black image. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your values are 16-bit and need to be reduced to 8-bit for display. You can scale them from their current range of 2,712 (i.e. `ims.min()`) to 4,328 (i.e. `ims.max()`) with the following:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import pickle

# Load image
ims = pickle.load(open("pixel_array.pickle", "rb"))

# Normalise to range 0..255
norm = (ims.astype(np.float)-ims.min())*255.0 / (ims.max()-ims.min())

# Save as 8-bit PNG
Image.fromarray(norm.astype(np.uint8)).save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: you saved my day! hero

Comment: @Mark:- Is there any way to display in 16 bit? (not in 8 bit)

Comment: @Sanjiv I've never really pursued that, maybe look here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_image_viewers

Comment: @MarkSetchell :- Mark Can you help me out with this:- `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59798243/does-pil-imageenhance-library-supports-16-bit-jpg-images`

Comment: @Sanjiv I have already commented on your question to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, can you please tell me how your question changes if the input already is a Pillow image, with no need to load it as a pickle? Thanks!