# Does PIL ImageEnhance library supports 16 bit JPG images

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, image-enhancement

I am trying to save and display 16 bit JPG image. but getting error like

> image has wrong mode
>   .

If Supported, then what will be the mode?

Comment: Also What will be the mode for `16 bit black & white` images?

Comment: Technically that is JPEG XT https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_XT and PIL doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

The mode (this is a string specifying the pixel format used by the image) of an image defines the type and depth of a pixel in the image. The current Python Imaging Library release only supports the following standard modes:

1 (1-bit pixels, black and white, stored with one pixel per byte)

L (8-bit pixels, black and white)

P (8-bit pixels, mapped to any other mode using a colour palette)

RGB (3x8-bit pixels, true colour)

RGBA (4x8-bit pixels, true colour with transparency mask)

CMYK (4x8-bit pixels, colour separation)

YCbCr (3x8-bit pixels, colour video format)

I (32-bit signed integer pixels)

F (32-bit floating-point pixels)

This may be the reason you are getting the above error. 
The Image.convert method creates, from an existing image, a new image with a given mode.
To know more about image attributes check the [link](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.mode) and about full concept check the [link](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/concepts.htm#mode).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I can't see any mode for 16 bit ?

Comment: Which is exactly what I also meant. The current Python Imaging Library release  supports only the following standard modes mentioned above,